# ADO.Net 2.0 vs 3.5

Tags: ado.net

what are the new features (if any) in ADO.Net 3.5 as compared to 2.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713697.aspx) ADO.NET 3.5 **SP1** includes the following new "feature":

> The .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server ( System.Data.SqlClient) provides full
>   support for all the new features of the SQL Server 2008 Database Engine

Also, I think the entity framework was introduced with that version.

Comment: so I would guess to say that you cannot use ADO.Net 2.0 framework with SQL 2008?

Comment: You can use ADO.NET 2.0 with SQL 2008, but you cannot use some new features of SQL 2008. See this page for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675218.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any major new features in straight ADO.NET itself.  But the big new feature is LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities (about to come out with a major upgrade with .NET 4.0).